# ¿Cómo usar una variable en una consulta MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de consultar un número de registros mediante el uso de una  variable sin obtener el resultado esperado.

```sql
SET @var = 0;

select *, @var:=(@var+1) as r 
from database 
where @var>10 
order by create_at;
```

Esa consulta genera 0 registros y si pongo `where @var=0` me los arroja todos. La idea es que arroje los registros cuyo valor de `@var` sea, mayor de 10 en este caso.

Comment: La lógica debería ser implemntada desde el backend y no desde la base de datos. Ese tipo de programación debe hacerse cuando es muy complicada la consulta, cosa que no es el caso

Comment: No tiene sentido lo que intentas hacer... parece que intentes hacer un *"loop"* para seleccionar todo menos los 10 primeros valores, puesto que intentas incrementar el valor de var en +1 y en el where tienes el `@var>10`... pero es que para eso puedes usar `OFFSET 10` y ya te saltará los 10 primeros.

Comment: A lo  mejor debería preguntarlo de otro modo. Lo que deseo es enumerar los registros de una tabla y hacer la consulta en función de ese dato. Es decir, en la misma consulta, generar la enumeración y filtrar en función de esos valores. Por ejemplo, si tengo 100 registros, ordenarlos por nombre, enumerarlos del 1 al 100 y coger los 10 primeros, o los que van del 30 al 40...

Comment: Pero es que lo que quieres hacer se hace con `LIMIT` o con `OFFSET`, no con cosas raras con variables. Cada cosa es para lo que es...

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que intentas hacer necesitas una subconsulta, tal que así:

```
set @var=0;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,@var:=@var+1 r FROM `database`  
  ) c1 WHERE r>10;
```

Aunque, como te comentan, con un simple:

```
SELECT * FROM `database`
  LIMIT 10,100;
```

O:

```
SELECT * FROM `database`
  LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10;
```

Obtendrías el mismo resultado, eso sí, sin los números `r` que habías asignado.